# Count all values in a column based on string in another column in R for a Venn diagram

Tags: r, replace, plot, dataframe

I have a file that I converted to a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
D <- data.frame(
    V1 =c("B", "A_B", "A_B_C", "C_D", "A_C", "C_B_D", "C", "C_A_B_D", "B_C", "C_A_D", "A_D", "D", "A", "B_D", "A_B_D"), 
    V2 = c(15057, 5, 9, 1090, 4, 1250, 3943, 11, 2517, 5, 5, 2280, 5, 1735, 4))
```

I need to convert this dataframe into a list of numbers that I can use to create a 4-way venn plot. In this example the values are the correct values if added correctly. I did this manually but since I need to create several similar plots I would like to find a way to do this more efficiently.

```
library("VennDiagram")
venn.plot <- draw.quad.venn(
  area1 = 48,
  area2 = 20588,
  area3 = 8829,
  area4 = 6380,
  n12 = 29,
  n13 = 29,
  n14 = 25,
  n23 = 3787,
  n24 = 3000,
  n34 = 2356,
  n123 = 20,
  n124 = 15,
  n134 = 16,
  n234 = 1261,
  n1234 = 11,
  category = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  fill = c("orange", "red", "green", "blue"),
  lty = "dashed",
  cex = 2,
  cat.cex = 2,
  cat.col = c("orange", "red", "green", "blue")
);
```

In this case I would need to count up all values from D$V2 that has an "A" in column V1 and so on. Then I would need to order appropriately for the venn plot function.

Comment: Do you need `sum(D$V2[grep('A', D$V1)])`

Comment: Does `A_B` mean that that value belongs to both category `A` and `B`?

Comment: Can you show the expected output?  If you need the count of A,B,C,D, may be `sapply(LETTERS[1:4], function(x) sum(D$V2[grep(x, D$V1)]))`

Comment: @akrun: Yes!! that works - now I just need to figure out how to order. Also, how would I use this if I'm looking at category "C_D" as the second commentator pointed out it would need to be included in: "area3", "area4", "n34", "n134", "n234" and "n1234".

Comment: I would suggest you to update the post with expected output so that it becomes easier to understand.

Comment: @akrun: Actually in the above example I manually added the numbers so the venn actually contains the correct values - I need to do this many times though which is why I'm asking. I also tried using the sapply but got four 0s

Comment: For me the `sapply` output based on the example you showed is `sapply(LETTERS[1:4], function(x) sum(D$V2[grep(x, D$V1)]))# 
    A     B     C     D 
   48 20588  8829  6380`

Comment: The area1 value 117 is different from the `sapply`.  Did you used a different dataset?

Comment: @akrun: yeah I accidentally used two different datasets in the example - I updated the question. Also I can now get the same results with the sapply, but still don't know how to get the different combinations and order

Comment: Not sure I understand about the combinations part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what I would do

```
# setup
myset = LETTERS[1:4]

# create dummies
D[,myset] <- lapply(myset, grepl, D$V1)

# construct counts
myn    <- length(myset)
mynums <- unlist(sapply(seq(myn), function(n) 
    apply(if (n==myn) matrix(seq(myn)) else combn(myn,n), 2, function(x)
        with(D, sum( V2[Reduce("&", mget(myset[x]))] ))
)))

# pass counts to plotter
do.call(draw.quad.venn, c(as.list(unname(mynums)), list(
  category = myset,
  fill = c("orange", "red", "green", "blue"),
  lty = "dashed",
  cex = 2,
  cat.cex = 2,
  cat.col = c("orange", "red", "green", "blue")
)))
```

[image]

Comment: this works great just one last question. Since I arbitrarily used "A", "B","C" and "D" in the example, each file actually has different names that are not always ordered alphabetically. Is there a way to change this so that the results are ordered by the list I use in "myset"?

Comment: @user2165857 Yes, I think that is the case already (since `combinations` takes `myset` as its "source vector").

Comment: Look at all the pretty colors, ooohhhh

Comment: @Frank: Actually it seems that the problem is with the combinations function. If I use "myset <- c("B", "A", "C", "D")" and then do "combinations(4, 1, myset)" I get the results in alphabetical order.

Comment: @user2165857 Oh, you're right. That isn't what I expected. I think the best way to go is like `myset[combn(4,1)]` to ensure they're ordered correctly. I'll switch to that in my answer.

Comment: @user2165857 Okay, it should work now. `combn` is annoying in that it doesn't always provide a matrix, so I had to throw in an `if...else` thing.