# Venn diagram of networks?

Tags: r, igraph, venn-diagram

I am using igraph on R and would like to create a Venn Diagram of multiple networks, to show how many edges they share. I haven't figured out an easy way to do this.

For instance:

```
> net1 <- graph.data.frame(data.frame(a=letters[1:10],b=letters[11:20]),
+                          directed=F)
> net2 <- graph.data.frame(data.frame(a=c(letters[1:5],letters[15:25]),
+                          b=c(letters[11:20],letters[c(21:26)])),
+                          directed=F)
> 
> net1_2 <- graph.intersection(net1,net2,keep.all.vertices=F)
> 
> net1
IGRAPH UN-- 20 10 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
> net2
IGRAPH UN-- 21 16 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
> net1_2
IGRAPH UN-- 15 5 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
```

And then do something like this, but that could work also on multiple networks, not only 2:

```
GraphsVenn(net1,net2)
```

[image]

If you are thinking why I don't just draw the merged network and color the intersection it's because the networks are huge and it would be a mess.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't have experience with igraph, but there are other packages for graphing Venn diagrams, like https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VennDiagram/index.html an illustration: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31681110

Comment: Thanks Frank, I know VennDiagram, the issue is that igraph edges are not read as vectors. So yes I could simply give in the numbers and draw the Venn Diagram, but I was wondering if there was a smarter way (I would have to do all the intersections of multiple networks which is long and error-prone).

Comment: `graph.intersection` (or simply `intersection` as it is called recently) does work on multiple networks: http://igraph.org/r/doc/intersection.igraph.html

Comment: Hi Gabor! That's awesome to talk to you... thanks for igraph! So my question was not how to do the intersection, but if there's an easy way (i.e. a function I don't know of) to draw a Venn diagram of networks intersections.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on igraph, but I think you can get a list of edges which might be the input for (among others) my `nVennR` package:

```
library(igraph)
library(nVennR)

net1 <- graph.data.frame(data.frame(a=letters[1:10],b=letters[11:20]), directed=F)
net2 <- graph.data.frame(data.frame(a=c(letters[1:5],letters[15:25]), b=c(letters[11:20],letters[c(21:26)])), directed=F)

myV <- plotVenn(list(net1=as_ids(E(net1)), net2=as_ids(E(net2))))
```

And the result:

[image: edges]

You can then query the elements in each region:

```
> listVennRegions(myV)
$`0, 1 (net2)`
 [1] "o|p" "p|q" "q|r" "r|s" "s|t" "t|u" "u|v" "v|w" "w|x" "x|y" "y|z"

$`1, 0 (net1)`
[1] "f|p" "g|q" "h|r" "i|s" "j|t"

$`1, 1 (net1, net2)`
[1] "a|k" "b|l" "c|m" "d|n" "e|o"
```

This package can handle any number of sets, although more than six is really slow and not very informative. If you are interested, there is a [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nVennR/vignettes/nVennR.html) with more information.